# Angular template from themeforest or similar

Tags: angular

I need a suggestion.  I am a beginner in angular.  I need to build a billing app and have chosen angular for it.

Would it be better and faster to purchase an angular admin template to start with from a website such as themeforest or similar website?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`ng-matero` is also a good admin template. It based on Angular Material, you can try it.

https://github.com/ng-matero/ng-matero

Features:

- Material Extensions
- Schematics support
- Modern design style
- Multiple admin layout
- Powerful color system
- Rich helpers
- Dark mode support
- RTL support
- Internationalization
- Authentication
- HTTP interceptors
- Permissions management

It's schematics is powerful. You can use `ng add` to initialize the project quickly and `ng generate` to create some business components.

Answer (score 1):

You can use open source admin template. `ngx-admin` is quite good.

https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin

Those guys have done a lot of things.

Attractive features:

- charts,
- custom form components,
- smart tables
- Auth

[Here](http://akveo.com/ngx-admin) is the demo.

Comment: Thank you. Is it easy to follow and build in for a beginner ?

Comment: yes, they provide many things those are ready to eat :) but you must have some knowledge of Angular before using any template.

Comment: I just completed a course on angular beginning from pluralsight. It should be good?

Comment: @user3855851 yes, that should be fine.

Comment: @user3855851 you can accept, upvote answer if it helped you.